# Why does redux not dispatch the updated object to the store?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to understand why I have to create a new object to manipulate and then dispatch to the store, instead of being able to dispatch the object instance that is passed to the function from the store.

For instance, if I have the following code:

```
export const doStuff = (
  stuff // stuff is from the store
) => dispatch => {
  stuff['foo'] = 'bar'

  console.log("stuff", stuff) // prints updated object

  dispatch({
    type: SET_STUFF,
    payload: stuff
  })
}
```

Then the DOM and state will not update.

However, if I do:

```
export const doStuff = (stuff) => dispatch => {
  const _stuff = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stuff))
  _stuff['foo'] = 'bar'

  console.log("_stuff", _stuff)

  dispatch({
    type: SET_STUFF,
    payload: _stuff
  })
}
```

Then, this will work. Why is this so?

I've looked at the documentation [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns/), but I am having trouble understanding it. Is `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` the only way to go about manipulating the state and updating it?

---

## Edit

My reducer:

```
case SET_STUFF:
    return {
      ...state,
      cartItems: payload
    };
```

Comment: You need to show the reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example - you are updating a property of an object. Not the object instance.
But in the second example you are actually creating new instance of an object.

You are experiencing [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15858) in the first example. So when you are modifying an object without creating a new instance(happens with arrays or list as well), react ignores that because states are treated as immutable objects. So you don't see any update. But in the second example you are creating a new instance and set that, that's why you see the updated value.

And I think even if you don't use `json.stringify`, rather just make a new instance and set that object as payload, you will see that it gets updated. like the following -

```
export const doStuff = (
  stuff // stuff is from the store
) => dispatch => {
  const new_stuff = {...stuff, 'foo': 'bar'};

  console.log("new stuff", new_stuff ) // prints updated object

  dispatch({
    type: SET_STUFF,
    payload: new_stuff 
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Also, `let new_stuff = stuff;` doesn't work, because `new_stuff === stuff` and, as you or the other person pointed out, Redux state is immutable, therefore the state won't update.

Comment: Sorry, `let` was just to give you an idea. I edited my answer. Check if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

since stuff is from the redux store and redux's state is immutable, if you pass the same object, you are essentially passing the reference to the same object which redux recognizes. However when you create a deep copy of the object, it is not passing the reference to the old object.

Comment: So, does everybody who experiences this issue make a deep copy of the object? Is there an alternative to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`?

Answer (score 0):

You should return a new instance in your reducer.
your reducer is not changing the state because you return the same instance
example how to update your state

```
SET_STUFF:
  return {...state, staff: action.payload}
```